# What's wrong with this Alloy code?

Tags: alloy

I get a syntax error message for the code below. 
The message designates the marked position in the addLocal assertion, stating:
"Syntax error at line 30 column 9: There are 1 possible tokens that can appear here: )"
I just can't see what's wrong here.

```
abstract sig Target{}

sig Addr extends Target{}
sig Name extends Target{}

sig Book
{
    addr: Name->Target
}

pred add(b, b1:Book, n:Name, t:Target)
{
    b1.addr = b.addr + (n->t)
}

fun lookup (b: Book, n: Name): set Addr 
{
    n.^(b.addr) & Addr
}

assert addLocal 
{
    all 
        b,b1:Book, 
        n,n1:Name, 
        t:Target |
            add(b, b1, n, t) and n != n1 => lookup(b, n1) = lookup(b1, n1)
            //   |- error position   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons I never quite understood, at some point Alloy's syntax changed from using (or allowing) parentheses around the arguments to predicates and functions, to requiring square brackets.  So the relevant line of `addLocal` needs to be re-punctuated:

```
    add[b, b1, n, t] and n != n1 => lookup[b, n1] = lookup[b1, n1]
```

I don't have the grammar firmly enough in my head to be sure, but a quick glance at the grammar in appendix B of *Software abstractions* suggests that parentheses can wrap the arguments in the predicate declaration, but not in a predicate reference; in an expression position, parentheses always wrap a single expression, which would explain why the parser stops when it encounters the first comma in the argument list.

Comment: I've just noticed that square brackets are accepted in the declarations as well: `pred add [b, b1: Book, n: Name, t: Target] {}`